# Join Entity with table that has no entity assosiated in JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a table that has no associated Entity. I need to write JPQL query which will filter by that table's fields. Is it possible?
I know that I can do one of the following:

1. Create an Entity for that table( but it's basically a join table, so it will look strange to create an Entity class for it)
2. Write a native query( I don't like this approach either. If I use JPA, I must use JPQL only).
3. Create fully functional ManyToMany mapping( I just don't need it).

Could there be another approach?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible but you can still write full join like... (Select table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.col = t2.col )

Comment: @Naman Do you mean in native query?

Comment: Not a native query. This is the query I have written (select r from rate r ,Product p where r.productId=p.id and r.id in(:id)) and I have used this query in entityManager.createQuery. And Here I had same issue that I had not association between entity.

Comment: @Naman Probably you didn't understand my situation. I have only one entity. I just need to join it with another table. Anyway, I've found a solution. I'll post it a little bit later, when I'm sure it does the job right.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot do that with JPQL.

You should use SQL. 
But a native query can also return Entities. Either if the returned values matches the entity or using @SqlResultSetMapping as described here:
http://javaee.support/sample/jpa-native-sql-resultset-mapping/

If you only need to join to entities on a relationship that is not mapped JPA 2.1 is able to JOIN on any table columns.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not need a real many-to-many object mapping but only collection of id's in my only entity. So I came to following solution:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(
   name="user_to_feed", 
   joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "feed_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
)
@Column(name="user_id")
private List<Integer> userIds = new ArrayList<>();
```

This allows me to make following query:

```
select f.url from Feed f join f.userIds u where :id in u
```